# Unique email in different models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 different models which contian email field:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailFields(unique=True)
    """
    other fileds
    """
class Model2(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailFields(unique=True)
    """
    other fileds
    """
```

These models don't have to contain the same emails. How can I do that?
Use `clean` method in each `ModelForm` for each models:

```
class Model1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ['email', ...]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if Model2.objects.filer(email=email).exists():
            self.add_error('email', 'Email have to be unique')
```

And as in other ModelForms?

Comment: What's your question? Doesn't your approach work?

Comment: You've spelt `filter` wrong (second line from bottom)

Comment: It works. But I want to know maybe is there better solution?

Comment: And how can I don't write the same things like 'self.add_error('email', 'Email have to be unique')' in each ModelsForms, for DRY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). Then all the emails will be stored in a single table, and the unique constraint will be handled at database label.

```
BaseModel(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailFields(unique=True)

class Model1(models.Model):
    # other fields

class Model2(models.Model):
    # other fields
```

If you do not want to use multi-table inheritance, you will have to manually check the other table as you are doing. To avoid repetition, maybe you can write a base model form class, and subclass it.